# Is there a sudoku app where the hint identifies the squares/logic to use to solve the next step?

Tags: sudoku

I have an app that has different levels of sudoku puzzles and I'm trying to learn to solve Expert.  The app I'm using has a hint function, but all it does is fill in the correct answer in a selected square.  That doesn't tell me why that's the correct answer or how I should have known it's the correct answer.

I've also found several web sites that explain different methods of solving squares, such as hidden triplets, x-wing, swordfish, etc.

I would like to use an app that has a hint function that doesn't give the answers, but instead maybe highlights a set of cells and says what method should be used on those cells to determine the answer, or to eliminate possible values.  That would help me to learn to apply the different logic methods.

Comment: I'm not certain if this question is within the scope of this Stack.  It would be useful to know what platform you were looking for this on.  On PC, I would suggest Duncan's Sudkou Solver.  For Android, I use Andoku Sudoku 3, it lets me take a picture of a sudoku and solve it on the app as well.  https://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm works too.  All of these options are from my history, there might be better newer options.

Comment: I'm on Android and I downloaded Andoku 3.  It's great and does everything I want.  Thanks!

Comment: It does. You need suffer some ads, but not so much: Guru Puzzle Game - Classic Sudoku   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sudoku.puzzle.free.game.brain